# Convert percentage to numbers, like 20% to 20

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard

I have a column which includes percentage values. The format of the column cells is "number".
[image]

This is a demo column. These are percentage values entered by user.

The code that I tried:

```
Sub Percent()
Dim cell As Variant
Dim cellValue As Variant
For Each cell In Selection
    With cell
        cellValue = .Text
        MsgBox cellValue
        If (cellValue Like "[0-9]*%") Then
            cellValue = Left(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - 1)
            .Value = cellValue
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

On running this, I want to convert the "selected cells" in numbers, i.e. I want to remove that percentage symbol, I don't want the values in decimals. Just the whole numbers (without the % symbol).

The code posted above works but the column should be a "text" column. That means, in "format cells" option for the column, it should say text not number, then only my code works. But when I change the column in "format cells" as "number", the code doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try adding the property as :
   .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value

Comment: You can reformat as Number and use PasteSpecial multiply (put 100 in an empty cell, copy, pastespecial).

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi I removed cellValue = Left(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - 1)
            .Value = cellValue     and added your two lines, and it worked perfectly. Just changed the .value = ,value * 100,  since your statement was giving me decimal values.  Thankyou so much.

Comment: @SJR   I'll try your suggestion. Thankyou for your time and effort.

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi post your comment as a separate answer so that i can mark your's as chosen answer for other users at doubt.

Comment: Sure Aman. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
Sub Percent()

    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim cellValue As Variant

    For Each cell In Selection
        With cell
            cellValue = .Text
            MsgBox cellValue
            If (cellValue Like "[0-9]*%") Then
                .NumberFormat = "General"    <-- convert the format into number
                .Value = .Value * 100        <--
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
Sub Percent()
Dim cell As Variant
Dim cellValue As Variant
For Each cell In Selection
    With cell
         .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        cellValue = .Value * 100
        .Value = cellValue
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

or this :

```
Sub Percent2()
Dim cell As Variant
Dim cellValue As Variant
For Each cell In Selection
    With cell
        cellValue = .Text
        MsgBox cellValue
        If (cellValue Like "[0-9]*%") Then
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
            cellValue = Left(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - 1)
            .Value = cellValue
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou. There's an IF statement missing that was in the question. Otherthan that perfect.

Comment: Thankyou. Works properly

Answer (score 0):

If you want numbers-as-text:

```
Sub Percent()
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    For Each cell In Selection
        With cell
            cellValue = .Text
            If Right(cellValue, 1) = "%" Then
                cellValue = "'" & Left(cellValue, Len(cellValue) - 1)
                .Value = cellValue
            Else

            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

We:

- modified the ***%*** test
- inserted a prefix character
- allowed the loop to continue

Comment: I tried it, The final values are "text" not "numbers". How can I convert it in numbers at the end ?

Comment: @AmanDevrath Just remove the single quote prefix in the code line with ***Left()***

Answer (score 0):

I would just convert the cell to a number first, multiply by 100, and convert to text.

```
Sub Percent()

    Dim Cel As Range

    For Each Cel In Selection.Cells
        With Cel
            .NumberFormat = "0.00"
            .Value2 = Round(.Value2 * 100, 0)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
        End With
    Next Cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou. I'll try it. BDW, what will the .numberFormat = "@" do ?

Comment: `.NumberFormat = "@"` sets a cell to the "Text" format

Comment: @AmanDevrath just adjusted it to round to whole numbers, missed that in the initial question

Comment: Thankyou for the answer.